# if php baseado em formulário select

Tags: php, html, formulário

estou tentando criar um formulário com modo de pagamento (A vista/Parcelado) e queria um novo campo disponivel apenas se a opção Parcelado esteja selecionada, porém sem ter que precionar submit

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">      
    <label for="campo3">Parcelas</label>    
    <select class="form-control" name="customer['parcelas']">
        <option value = "0" selected>A vista</option>
        <option value = "10">Parcelado</option>
        
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php if($customer['parcelas']>0){ echo 
                "<div class='form-group col-md-4'>     
    <label for='campo3'>Parcelas</label>    
    <select class='form-control' name='customer['parcelas']'>
        <option value = '0' selected>A vista</option>
        <option value = '10'>Parcelado</option>
        
        </select>
    </div>";} ?>
```

Comment: ignorem o fato de que o código se repete, apenas queria demonstrar um echo em html antes de trabalhar no segundo form

Comment: não esqueça de converte-lo para int (intval), e antes disto também verificar se é um valor válido para tal conversão (is_numeric), para poder compara-lo como um numero